# Example of optimal delta hedging in G. Barles, H.M. Soner option pricing paper

Tags: options, option-pricing, hedging, delta-hedging, delta-neutral

There is a paper [Option pricing with transaction costs and a nonlinear black-scholes equation](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~hmsoner/pdfs/38-Soner-FS-98.pdf) by Guy Barles and Halil Mete Soner. And there is a section about optimal (delta) hedging, which I do not fully understand.

The conclusion of optimal hedge section states that:
[image: part of pdf]

So what is g() here? I couldn't find it's definition previously. Can someone give a real (numeric) example of calculations according to this model? I mean something like: we sell a call/put with strike S, it's delta is d, T days to expiration, etc. And after calculation we get the interval [y1, y2].